# Using html2canvas to get screenshot of google maps Vector

Tags: vector, maps, html2canvas

I`m trying to get a screenshot of a div with google map vector. Trying the same using map type raster this worked. But i need to do this with google map **vector** v=beta

with option useCors: true the map stay blank.

The markers appear

My code:

```
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#map-area"),{useCORS: true,allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas) {
    
                    imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

                    doc.addImage(imgData,'JPEG', 0, 0, 1790, 1260,'','FAST');
    
                    doc.save('map.pdf');
    
                });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding this before anything this worked ok:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
    return function(type, attribs) {
    attribs = attribs || {};
    attribs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
    return origFn.call(this, type, attribs);
    };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);
```